# Error "The absolute uri: http://struts.apache.org/tags-html cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application "

Tags: web.xml, struts-config, struts-1

i am new to Struts.i have tried an sample struts1.x application.when i run it ,it gives an error

> The absolute uri: http://struts.apache.org/tags-html cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application" my jsp page has 
>   '<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>
>   <%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>'

web page:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <center>
      <html:errors/>
      <html:form action="login">
        <bean:message key="label.uname"/>
        :
        <html:text property="uname"/>
        <br> 
        <bean:message key="label.pwd"/>
        :
        <html:text property="pwd"/>
        <br> 
        <html:submit value="LOGIN"/>
      </html:form>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.Action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>Config</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Include the below `jar` as dependency [in `WEB-INF/lib`]

```
 struts-taglib.jar [any version, eg: struts-taglib-1.3.10.jar]
```

In JSP page :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic" %>
```

How this works: The  tag library descriptor [tld] information are defined inside the “struts-taglib.jar\META-INF\tld”

You can have a look at the answer mentioned in this SO post. I have a running example there
[No getter method for property... error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593878/no-getter-method-for-property-error/21596521#21596521)

So either you can have the jar file as dependency or add the tag library descriptors inside your WEB-INF, and configure in `web.xml`

**web.xml**

```
<taglib>
     <taglib-uri>
      http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean
     </taglib-uri>
     <taglib-location>
      /WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld
     </taglib-location>
</taglib>
<taglib>
     <taglib-uri>
      http://struts.apache.org/tags-html
     </taglib-uri>
     <taglib-location>
      /WEB-INF/struts-html.tld
     </taglib-location>
</taglib>
<taglib>
     <taglib-uri>
      http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic
     </taglib-uri>
     <taglib-location>
      /WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld
     </taglib-location>
</taglib>
```

There is a mapping between what you configure here and the `taglib` you define in jsp page.
The `@taglib uri` in the jsp page have to match with `<taglib-uri>` defined in `web.xml`

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply you have to check **Add Struts TLDs** option while creating project.
As shown below in a screen-shot.
[image: Add Struts TLDs]

**Add Struts TLDs**: Lets you generate tag library descriptors for the Struts tag libraries. A tag library descriptor is an XML document which contains additional information about the entire tag library as well as each individual tag. In general this is not necessary, because you can refer to on-line URIs rather than local TLD files.