# No getter method for property... error

Tags: java, spring, jsp, struts

I am unable to find out what I am doing wrong.

I get this error:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: No getter method for property: "firstname" of bean: "org.apache.struts.validator.DynaValidatorForm"
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.TagUtils.lookup(TagUtils.java:915)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.html.BaseFieldTag.prepareValue(BaseFieldTag.java:126)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.html.BaseFieldTag.renderInputElement(BaseFieldTag.java:102)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.html.BaseFieldTag.doStartTag(BaseFieldTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspx_meth_html_005ftext_005f1(login_jsp.java:1095)
    at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspx_meth_html_005fform_005f1(login_jsp.java:1040)
    at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:759)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

in the struts-config.xml file the tage  is used:

```
<form-bean name="sendContactForm" type="org.apache.struts.validator.DynaValidatorForm">
            <form-property name="firstname" type="java.lang.String" initial="firstname"/>
            <form-property name="lastname" type="java.lang.String" initial="lastname"/>
            <form-property name="emailaddress" type="java.lang.String" initial="email"/>
            <form-property name="subject" type="java.lang.String" initial="subject"/>
            <form-property name="comments" type="java.lang.String" initial="comments"/>
        </form-bean>
```

and also:

```
<action path="/sendContactForm" attribute="sendContactForm" input="/login.jsp"
            name="sendContactForm" scope="request"  parameter="reqCode"
            type="org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingActionProxy" validate="true">
            <forward name="sendcontacts" path="/login.jsp"/>
        </action>
```

in Actionform I have:

```
public class ContactAction extends DynaValidatorActionForm {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ContactAction.class);


public ActionForward sendContactForm(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws Exception {
            log.debug("ContactForm--start");


DynaValidatorActionForm sendContactForm = (DynaValidatorActionForm) form;
ActionMessages messages = new ActionMessages();

String firstName = ((String) sendContactForm.get("firstname"));
String lastName = ((String) sendContactForm.get("lastname"));
String emailAddress = ((String) sendContactForm.get("emailaddress"));
String subject = ((String) sendContactForm.get("subject"));
String comments = ((String) sendContactForm.get("comments"));
return mapping.findForward("sendcontacts");
```

In the jsp file I have:

```
    <html:form action="/sendContactForm.do?ContactCd=sendContactForm" method="post" styleId="sendContactForm">
    <c:set var="sendContactForm" value="${sendContactForm}" />

    <html:errors/>           



        <label for="firstname">First Name  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        </label>
            <html:text styleId="firstname" property="firstname" styleClass="form-control tip required"  name="sendContactForm" />



        <label for="lastname">Last Name  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        </label>
        <html:text styleId="lastname" property="lastname" styleClass="form-control tip pplaceholder" name="sendContactForm"/>



        <label for="emailaddress">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        </label>
        <html:text styleId="emailaddress" property="emailaddress" styleClass="form-control tip pplaceholder"  name="sendContactForm" />


        <label for="subject">Subject  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        </label>
        <html:text styleId="subject" property="subject" styleClass="form-control tip pplaceholder" name="sendContactForm"/>

             <label for="comments">Comments  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        </label>
        <html:textarea styleId="comments" property="comments" styleClass="form-control tip pplaceholder" name="sendContactForm"></html:textarea>

</html:form>
```

I have researched a lot but wasn't success yet.

So, what's wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Major UPDATE:**

I tried out your code with the changes I mentioned here, and the login page with all those five fields are getting displayed with their default initial values that were given in form-bean definition. There are no errors in displaying the page.

Another thing to note here is that your login.jsp has no submit button and you are not all submitting the form, so the control never comes inside your action class.

This is the login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<html:form action="/sendContactForm.do?ContactCd=sendContactForm"
        method="post" styleId="sendContactForm">
        <c:set var="sendContactForm" value="${sendContactForm}" />

        <html:errors />



        <label for="firstname">First Name <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        </label>
        <html:text styleId="firstname" property="firstname"
            styleClass="form-control tip required" name="sendContactForm" />



        <label for="lastname">Last Name <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        </label>
        <html:text styleId="lastname" property="lastname"
            styleClass="form-control tip pplaceholder" name="sendContactForm" />



        <label for="emailaddress">Email Address <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        </label>
        <html:text styleId="emailaddress" property="emailaddress"
            styleClass="form-control tip pplaceholder" name="sendContactForm" />


        <label for="subject">Subject <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        </label>
        <html:text styleId="subject" property="subject"
            styleClass="form-control tip pplaceholder" name="sendContactForm" />

        <label for="comments">Comments <span class="asterisk">*</span>
        </label>
        <html:textarea styleId="comments" property="comments"
            styleClass="form-control tip pplaceholder" name="sendContactForm"></html:textarea>

    </html:form>


</body>
</html>
```

The jars used are

`struts-taglib-1.3.10.jar,struts-core-1.3.10.jar,jstl-1.2.jar,commons-validator-1.3.1.jar,
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar,commons-digester-1.8.jar,commons-chain-1.2.jar,commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar,antlr-2.7.2.jar`

The following tld's are put inside my `WEB-INF`

`struts-bean.tld, struts-html.tld,struts-logic.tld`

If you have any validation, `validation.xml` may also be present in WEB-INF

ContactAction.java  [in your current case, control does not come here]

```
public class ContactAction extends Action {

    @Override
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws Exception {

        DynaValidatorForm sendContactForm = (DynaValidatorForm) form;
        ActionMessages messages = new ActionMessages();

        String firstName = ((String) sendContactForm.get("firstname"));
        String lastName = ((String) sendContactForm.get("lastname"));
        String emailAddress = ((String) sendContactForm.get("emailaddress"));
        String subject = ((String) sendContactForm.get("subject"));
        String comments = ((String) sendContactForm.get("comments"));
        return mapping.findForward("sendcontacts");
    }
}
```

**Previous edits**
Usage of  `sendContactForm.get("firstname")` is correct, as you are using `DynaValidatorForm`.

The error is that your action class is extending the wrong class.

```
public class ContactAction extends DynaValidatorActionForm
```

This is wrong. You need to extend the `Action` class
ie:

```
public class ContactAction extends Action
```

Also, instead of

```
DynaValidatorActionForm sendContactForm = (DynaValidatorActionForm) form;
```

use

```
DynaValidatorForm sendContactForm = (DynaValidatorForm) form;
```

Update:
In your action class,

what is this method name - `sendContactForm` ? Is there any reason for this?

```
public ActionForward sendContactForm
```

Why don't you change it to
`public ActionForward execute`

Comment: I tried this also. Didn't solve the issue. In the browser, it stop showing fields after emailaddress but in the console it says that No getter method for property: "firstname"!!

Comment: By default getFirstname () will be called.  When you are putting debug points inside actin class do you see things as expected?

Comment: i will try and will let you know

Comment: No need to put the tld's in WEB-INF since we are using the struts-taglib-1.3.10.jar as a dependency jar

Answer (score 0):

I am shooting in the dark here(don't have much idea of struts) but seems like you are calling getter function[((String) sendContactForm.get("firstname"));] from some bean and it is giving error no getter function. 
So have you created getter function for "firstname"?

Comment: Are you saving the data you got from JSP?
Instead of "sendContactForm.Get()" try using "sendContactForm.getParameter()".

Comment: Or you may be missing Bean file as I said. Something like this.
public class UploadForm extends ActionForm {

    protected String myText;
    protected FormFile myFile;

    public void setMyText(String text) {
        myText = text;
    }

    public String getMyText() {
        return myText;
    }

    public void setMyFile(FormFile file) {
        myFile = file;
    }

    public FormFile getMyFile() {
        return myFile;
    }

}

Comment: I don't save the data. I am going to test that class.

Comment: I tested that but not success.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Got your problem.

Try this.

Instead of using "String firstName = ((String) sendContactForm.get("firstname"));"

Use this

String firstName = req.getParameter("firstName"));

This will solve your issue. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very much used to `DynaActionForms`, always used `ActionForm`.

Just out of curiosity, does it work if you change `firstname` to `firstName` in form definition and all other places you are referring it?